# Javascript-like objects in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, object

It's pretty handy in JS to create objects like this:

```
test = { foo : { bar : "hello world" }, bar2 : "hello world 2" }
```

and then use them like:

```
test.foo.bar
test.bar2
```

Is there anything like this in PHP without declaring classes?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

stdClass allows you to create (essentially) typeless objects.  For example:

```
$object = (object) array(
    'name' => 'Trevor',
    'age' => 42
);
```

As shown here, the fastest way to create a stdClass object is to cast an associative array.  For multiple levels, you just do the same thing again inside like this:

```
$object = (object) array(
    'name' => 'Trevor',
    'age' => '42',
    'car' => (object) array(
        'make' => 'Mini Cooper',
        'model' => 'S',
        'year' => 2010
     )
);
```

Another method is to convert the associative array to an object afterwards with a recursive function.  Here's an example.

```
function toObject(array $array) {
    $array = (object) $array;
    foreach ($array as &$value)
        if (is_array($value))
            $value = toObject($value);

    return $array;
}
// usage:
$array = // some big hierarchical associative array...
$array = toObject($array);
```

This is useful when you're not the one making the associative array.

Unfortunately, even though PHP 5.3 supports anonymous methods, you cannot put an anonymous method into a stdClass (though you can put one into an associative array).  But this isn't too bad anyway; if you want functionality in it, you really should create a class instead.

Answer (score 19):

It's called associative arrays.

Example (note: the indentation is for layout purposes):

```
$test = array(
  'foo' => array(
     'bar' => 'hello world'
   ),
  'bar2' => 'hello world 2'
);
$test['foo']['bar'];
$test['bar2'];
```

This is equivalent to the following Javascript code:

```
var test = {
  'foo': {
    'bar': 'hello world',
  },
  'bar2': 'hello world 2'
};
```

As an alternative, you can use the pre-declared StdClass.

```
$test = new StdClass;
$test->foo = new StdClass;
$test->foo->bar = 'hello world';
$test->bar2 = 'hello world 2';
```

which would be written in JavaScript as:

```
var test = new Object;
test.foo = new Object;
test.foo.bar = 'hello world';
test.bar2 = 'hello world 2';
```

(note: `new Object` is the same as `{}` in Javascript)

Comment: *(nitpick)* Objects are not the same as Associative Arrays, so the first two examples are not *equivalent*. Using json_encode on the assoc array would produce JavaScript objects because there is no assoc arrays in JavaScript but this is not true for using json_decode on the JavaScript object. By default, json_decode will return objects for this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a StdClass object or an ArrayObject which are included in php (though the latter requires that you have SPL installed). Though unless you need to access the values specifically with the `->` operator its more efficient to just use an associative array instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is an `Associative Array`

```
$test["foo"]["bar"]
```

http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=keyed+arrays

Comment: `test` is a constant. It should be `$test`.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing would be arrays.

```
$test = array(
  'foo' => array('bar' => 'hello world'),
  'bar2' => 'hello world 2',
);

echo $test['foo']['bar'];
```

Comment: Well I know about arrays. I was asking specifically about objects as they're more flexible, e.g. if you want to you can add methods, not just data.

Comment: How are objects more flexible in this case?  You cant add methods to a **StdClass** object like you can in JavaScript.  The closest you can get is declaring a property in the StdClass object and assign it an object that has the methods you need.  You can just as easily do this with arrays.  The **only** thing that differs is the syntax used to get what you need; I dont see any differences in flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, no. However if you are creating a data object (ie no methods), you could technically write a JSON string and use

```
$obj = json_decode($obj_string);
```

I wouldn't recommend it however. I assume there would be significant speed loss.

**EDIT**
Though it goes without mentioning, associative arrays should be used for this instead of flat data objects.

Comment: *(sidenote)* the OP is missing quotes around the properties though, so `json_decode` won't return anything because it's invalid Json.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason to do that is if you wish to pass data back to a JavaScript function with JSON.  In that case, use json_encode on the array.  Otherwise, just keep it as an array, as there's not reason to encode it and then decode it just so it looks like JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way: https://github.com/ptrofimov/jslikeobject

Author implemented JS-like objects, you can even access properties from functions via $this pointer.

But perhaps it is not so good to use such objects instead of usual ones.

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = array(
'a'=> 123,
'b'=> 334,
'c'=> 7853
 );
echo json_encode($a);
```

This will be the result: `{"a":123,"b":334,"c":7853}`